# Log file error in opening eclipse

Tags: eclipse, windows

When I open Eclipse, I get this log file error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-09-11 08:59:13.474
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.readArray(TableReader.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.basicLoadExtensionPoint(TableReader.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.loadExtensionPoint(TableReader.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.TableReader.loadExtensionPointTree(TableReader.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.load(RegistryObjectManager.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.basicGetObject(RegistryObjectManager.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.RegistryObjectManager.getObject(RegistryObjectManager.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.BaseExtensionPointHandle.getExtensionPoint(BaseExtensionPointHandle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.BaseExtensionPointHandle.getConfigurationElements(BaseExtensionPointHandle.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.getConfigurationElementsFor(ExtensionRegistry.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.getConfigurationElementsFor(ExtensionRegistry.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.contexts.ContextPersistence.read(ContextPersistence.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.contexts.ContextService.readRegistry(ContextService.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$45.runWithException(Workbench.java:1825)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You IDE eclipse creating problem i think your OS is crupt due to this eclipse EclipseAppLauncher and EclipseAppHandle both are not running properly  so please delete your old eclipse try to download new one and try, if receive same error reinstall your OS.